# Dynamodb BETWEEN operation for strings

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I cannot find any detailed documentation for dynamodb BETWEEN operator especially how it deals with strings.

For example if I make queries like "... sort_key Between '100' and '150' " and sort key is "120" then it works correct. 
But if I make strings like "1224|67" or "6653|67" and then query for 
 between "3456|67"  and "8968|67", it doesn't work. How to get information how this comparison works internally?

Answer (score 2):

In your case you need to use **expression attribute names** and **expression attribute values**. This is a very good practice in any DynamoDB query.

Please note that you'll also need to set a *partition key* (see `#pk` and `:pk` below).

```sh
aws dynamodb query \
    --table-name TABLE_NAME \
    --key-condition-expression "#pk = :pk AND #sk BETWEEN :a and :b" \
    --expression-attribute-names '{"#sk": "sort_key", "#pk": "partition_key"}' \
    --expression-attribute-values '{":a": {"S":"3456|67"}, ":b": {"S":"8968|67"}, ":pk":{"S":"partition_key_value"}}'
```

I didn't use this syntax for a while, there may me some small syntax error, but this is what you have to do in order to query with `BETWEEN`.

See the last example about [KeyConditions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LegacyConditionalParameters.KeyConditions.html):

```sh
aws dynamodb query \
    --table-name Music \
    --key-condition-expression 'Artist = :a AND SongTitle BETWEEN :t1 AND :t2' \
    --expression-attribute-values '{
        ":a": {"S": "No One You Know"}, 
        ":t1": {"S": "A"}, 
        ":t2": {"S": "M"}
    }'
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer, this is exactly how I do but I'm using boto3. The point of my question is that sometimes I'm getting bizarre results when I make queries with compound strings. Seems it works for strings which are separated by "_" instead of "|".

Comment: Interesting... I cannot test it now, but I'll give it a try. Do you have a deadline soon or can it wait for the weekend? And what do you mean by "**sometimes**"? Feel free to edit the question to explain that "sometimes" :)

Comment: Hi, I will be grateful for any information. About the "sometimes", I meant that it works unpredictable. For example If I query with hash key like: "{timestamp}_{id}" it doesn't work, but "{id}_{timestamp}" works. With "|" as separator sometimes works sometimes not (unperictable).

Comment: @Kirimaks you may want to zero-pad the elements of your compound strings, e.g. `000123|000420`. That's because dynamo comparison is lexicographical, meaning that `1 < 10 < 2` and you probably want `1 < 2 < 10`, so make it `01 < 02 < 10`.

Comment: You are right @DimaTisnek, it is often necessary to pad the content